# If $z=a+ib\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, then there exist a unique $\theta\in (-\pi, \pi]$ such that $a=|z|\cos \theta$ and $b=|z|\sin \theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Given a non-zero complex number $z=a+ib$, I want to show that there exists a unique $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi]$, satisfying the equations
$$a=|z|\cos \theta,\mbox{and } b=|z|\sin \theta.$$
Now, since $|a|\leq|z|$, we deduce the inequality

$$-1\leq\dfrac{a}{|z|}\leq 1.$$
Also as $\cos:[0,\pi]\to [-1,1]$ is bijective, there exist a unique $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ such that $\cos \theta =\frac{a}{|z|} \implies a=|z|\cos \theta.$ Next I will show that for this same $\theta$, the equation $b=|z|\sin \theta$ is also satisfied.
We have,
$$|z|\sin \theta=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\sin^2 \theta}
=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(1-\cos^2 \theta)}=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)-(a^2+b^2)\cos^2\theta}\\
=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)-|z|^2\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)-a^2}\\
=\sqrt{b^2}=b.$$

Thus we have got a unique $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ satisfying the above two equations but **NOT** in $(-\pi,\pi]$. What is wrong with my calculations? what did I miss? In many complex analysis books, I have seen this $\theta$ is nothing but the principal argument of $z$, and it should lie in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. Please help anyone I'm confused.

Comment: The very last identity does not hold if b is negative.

Comment: Choose $z=-i$ and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  So in the case when $b$ is negative I should choose $\theta$ from $[-\pi,0]$ or what?

Comment: By the unit circle definition of sin and cos, the curve $\gamma(t)=(\sin t,\cos t)$ parameterizes the unit circle with period $2\pi$.  So for any half-open interval of length $2\pi$, if $x^2+y^2=1$, then there is a unique $t$ such that $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$.  Take $x=a/|z|, y=b/|z|$.  Assuming that $x\neq 0$, there are two solutions in the interval to $\tan t = y/x$, and so it's just a matter of picking which of the two to take, which will depend on the signs of x and y.

Comment: Start with $b/\lvert z \rvert = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=|z|(cosθ+isinθ)$, then $cosθ=\frac {x}{|z|}$ and $sinθ=\frac {y}{|z|}, z\neq 0$ (1). If $θ\in (-π,π]$, then there is a unique $θ$ that satisfies both equations (1), because the functions sine and cosine have period $2π$, so there is no $T\in \Bbb R$, such that $θ+T\in (-π,π]$ and $cosθ=cos(θ+Τ)$ or $sinθ=sin(θ+Τ)$.

The answer about existence of such a $θ$ is trivial. Let a complex number $z=x+yi, x,y\in \Bbb R$.We define $|z|^2:=x^2+y^2$, so there exists a $θ$, such that $x=|z|cosθ, y=|z|sinθ$, for $x^2+y^2=(|z|cosθ)^2+(|z|sinθ)^2=|z|^2(cos^2θ+sin^2θ)=|z|^2$.

Comment: I'm asking for the existence of such $\theta$ and you right away start with..

Comment: Your question is not clear. I answered on the uniqueness.

Comment: Im asking both the existence and uniqueness of $\theta$

Comment: The task of existence is trivial (all complex analysis books I know, give θ simply by a geometric representation of a complex number), although I added an answer about it above.